# Solving recurrence with moebius inversion

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, recursion

what's up folks?

I'm solving the red book of math problems, problem 16 which is to solve the following recurrence relation:

$\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} a(k) = \frac{n}{n+1}$

PS: ${n \choose k}  = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ (it is not the Legendre symbol).

for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Moebius Inversion formula with

$G(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ (one can define it to be zero if $0<x<1$)

and some $F$ I know one can use differential equations theory to solve this one, but I want to try to solve it by this way

spoiler alert: $a(k) = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}$

Comment: Take a look to the syntax for the binomial coefficients

Comment: It looks like an application of the Pascal's inversion formula.

Comment: I used the Pascal relation, didn't got much better. Got on another linear recurrence most of the terms don't cancel themselves

Comment: Did you know for $f(s)=\frac{s}{s+1}$ and $H_s=\gamma+\psi ^{(0)}(s+1)$ (analytic Harmonic number function), $f(s)=\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^K\frac{\mu(n)}{n} H_{\frac{s}{n}}\right)$ and $H_s=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^K\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)\right)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

It is known that if $f(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}g(i)$ for all $0 \le n \le m$, then $g(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i+n}\binom{n}{i} f(i)$ for $0 \le n \le m$.

This sort of inversion is called *Pascal's inversion formula*

In order to complete the sum to start from $0$ you can assume that $\alpha(0)=0$.

**Edit**
$$\alpha(n)=(-1)^n\frac{3n^2-n}{2}$$

Comment: A.k.a. Pascal's inversion formula (+1).

Comment: I thought you were being ironic about Pascal inversion. Thank you both

Comment: just another thing would it be $f(i)$ in the last equation ?

Comment: Yes you're right I corrected it

Comment: for n=1 your answer don't match the recurrence relation